# Copy (e.g. with load or find) with jQuery an HTML Markup with included Inline Script - How to realize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I want to crop a part of an HTML markup with Inline-JavaScript included.

Example:

```
<div id="foo">
   <div id="bar">
      <script>
         ..some function..
      </script>
      <p>...</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

With the jQuery functions find() and load() you are not able to copy the whole markup WITH the JS-Snippet includet. The result looks like:

```
<div id="foo">
   <div id="bar">
      <p>...</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

The Script is stripped off. In the jQuery Community they say its supposed to be like this, because of risk of Script Injection.

But how is it possible anyway to realize this?

Best wishes
chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-removing-script-tags-from-html-string-when-using-html

Is a good thread on this.

I guess you could always use innerHTML which I believe returns the script.

Comment: Good answer by bobince, but your answer/link helped me with my problem - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's not to do with script injection at `html()`-reading time, it's to do with browser inconsistencies about what happens when you write `<script>` into `innerHTML`, at `html(value)`-writing time.

This is heavily unreliable across browsers, which is why jQuery attempts to pull the scripts out and execute them separately, avoiding writing them to the document since that has unpredictable after-effects.

You should avoid dealing with `script` element nodes or HTML markup with `<script>` in. What is it you are trying to do here?

Comment: Short version: We have build a kind of slide show, which loads content "snippets" out of other files (thats why we crop from this node) into the container. Works fine, till we load a page with an included flash video player, that is using swfobject.js script to initialize. :-) Clear?

Comment: Have you thought about escaping the <script> tag? &lt;script&gt; ?

Comment: Loading scripts dynamically like this is unwise, you want to keep your code static. When you *really* need to, you should return separate script for explicit execution. But for a simple Flash video player there is no benefit to using swfobject; you can just use the simple object markup detailed in the [Flash Satay](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashsatay) article and forget scripting. The disadvantage of this method of embedding is that you don't get swf-loading-streaming in IE. But video players don't provide that anyway, they load completely (and then take video from an external URL).